# Unable to access CDI

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, mojarra

I have a class that contains a method annotated with @PostConstruct which fetchs list of customers

```
    @ViewScoped
    @Named
 public class CustomerController extends AlertResponse {
  @PostConstruct
    public List<Customer> init() {
    ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> listResponse =
            restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8030/api/customers/listCustomers",
                    HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                    });
    customersList = listResponse.getBody();
    return customersList;
}
```

When i run the application i get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI
at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:65)
at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.createDataModel(CdiUtils.java:308)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:255)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:465)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:515)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1081)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1648)
at org.primefaces.component.column.Column.renderChildren(Column.java:90)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:1356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:1272)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:1179)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:1119)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:1072)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:401)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:331)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.render(DataTableRenderer.java:106)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:97)
```

When i removed these lines, the view is rendred fine

```
           <p:column headerText="Customer Status" sortBy="#{customer.customerStatus}"
                          filterBy="#{customer.customerStatus}">
                    <ui:repeat value="#{customer}" var="data">
                                                <h:outputText rendered="#{data.customerStatus == 'Unlocked'}">
                                                    <p:tag styleClass="p-mr-2" severity="success" value="UnLocked"
                                                           rounded="true"/>
                                                </h:outputText>
                                                <h:outputText rendered="#{data.customerStatus == 'Locked'}">
                                                    <p:tag styleClass="p-mr-2" severity="danger" value="Locked"
                                                           rounded="true"/>

                                                </h:outputText>
                                            </ui:repeat>
                </p:column>
```

What could be the problem
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

@PostConstruct is for initialization purposes like opening a database connection. Methods annotated with @PostConstruct must have void return type and no parameter:

```
void init() { ...
```

Comment: That's not the problem bro; it was working fine when i was using myfaces, when i migrate to mojarra i get this error, the problem is coming from <ui:repeat> tag

Comment: `<ui:repeat value="#{customer}"` its not able to lookup from where the value should be pick up.. Please have a look over here